# Why consuming WCF web service from ASP.NET 1.1 needs XmlSerializerFormat attribute in the ServiceContract

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, web-services, endpoint

I am *consuming a a WCF web service from APS.NET 1.1* and I read in everywhere that we need to

1 : Add **XmlSerializerFormat attribute** to the ServiceContract we want to consume.

2 : Use **basicHttpBinding** as Endpoint setting.

**Why so?**

> -> Is it possible to set the POINT 1 condition someway in configuration file ?
>
> -> When basicHttpBinding's default is XML serialization. Why do we need to explicitly declare the service contract as XmlSerializerFormat
>   ?

Comment: You cannot change the serializer of a single binding but you can specify that a particular serivce can use DataContract or Xmlserializer by just adding the XMLSerializerAttribute on the service contract.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, I do not think WCF provides a way to override default serializer (i.e. DataContractSerializer). You however can create custom Service\Operation Behavior, define configuration element for custom Operation Behavior and use this to override serializer.

Default serializer of `BasicHttpBinding` is DataContractSerializer, NOT XmlSerializer. Both serializers work differently (although produce xml output). You can checkout the difference between behavior of these two serializers.

Comment: So how can I make the serializer of **BasicHttpBinding** as XMLSerializer?